# Is transcendental meditation pseudoscience?

Tags: meditation

Is transcendental meditation pseudoscience or it is confirmed by official medical science? Does students learn it at study?

Comment: It's rude to cross-post on multiple SE sites. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of this cross-posted question https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/27084/is-transcendental-meditation-pseudoscience